# Execute code when user changes to silent mode in Android

Tags: android

I'm using a service. In that service my code should get executed when the user changes to silent mode, i.e. as soon as the user changes to silent mode, my code needs to get executed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want use a service. Instead you want to use a [BroadcastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that filters for the android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED Intent.

You might want to take a look at this [project](http://code.google.com/p/android-phone-silencer/) as it deals with the phone being silenced. It probably has some source code that will be useful to you.

Comment: thanks Kurits Nusbaum.is it possible to run a code as soon as the user turns on the silent mode

Comment: @jehan Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find a particular post useful or helpful. Please vote it up. If you think a particular answer is right, please accept it. It is indeed possible to run arbitrary code when the user goes into silent mode. You'd just check if the Intent you received in your BroadcastReciever tells you whether or not the volume is now set to muted. If so, run what ever code you want.

Comment: how to view code from apk file?? i installed the file,the what do I do ?

Comment: @jehan If you have other questions not related to the one you asked here, please start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can register to listen to the Broadcast`AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION`.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you can register the intent like this

```
<intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED"  />
                          </intent-filter>
```

And then recieve the intent at method

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

of class that extends **BroadcastReceiver** class