# Broadcast receiver for Silent Mode detection?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SILENT MODE ANDROID EVENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830240/silent-mode-android-event)

I would like to know about the permission to detect change in profile(from normal to silent or vice versa),so that I can execute my code in the broadcast receiver.